# Mysql Workbench Error when i press on any table in the workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The error is appearing when I press on any table
[image: The error is APPEARING when I press on any table]

Comment: when mysql tell yyou you have the column you haven't the column, so without any tables and a image for the select, nobody can help you

Comment: Here, the workbench tries to retrieve information about a user from the built-in system view called `mysql.user`, but finds a missing column. That means the workbench thinks it's talking to a more recent version of the mysql server than you are running. Check the properties of your connection.

Comment: In fact, i was working on MariaDb instead of Mysql ( I forgot to put port 3308 instead of 3306 ) . Thanks for your help !